# Let $H$ be a Laplacian. Is the covariant derivative $\nabla$ such that $H+\operatorname{Tr}(\nabla^2)$ is of order zero unique?

Tags: differential-operators

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over a Riemannian manifold $M$. Furthermore let $H$ be a generalized Laplacian, i.e.
$$\forall f\in C^\infty(M):[[H,f],f]=-|df|^2.$$
Proposition 2.5 in [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628) says that there is a covariant derivative $\nabla$ on $E$ such that $H$ and $\Delta:=-\operatorname{Tr}(\nabla^2)$ only differ by a differential operator of zeroth order, i.e. $F:=H-\Delta$ satisfies
$$\forall f\in C^\infty(M):[F,f]=0.$$
I would like to show that $\nabla$ is unique$^1$, can someone help me out?

---

$^1$ This is true according to proposition $10.1.34$ in [Nicolaescu's notes](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Lectures.pdf) (note that $\Delta=\nabla^*\nabla$ if we are in addition given a metric on $E$ which is compatible with $\nabla$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\nabla$ and $\widetilde\nabla$ be two connections on your bundle. There exists some section $A$ of $T^*M\otimes\operatorname{End}E$ such that $\widetilde\nabla=\nabla+A$, say acting on sections with compact support.

I assume that the manifold and the bundle both have a metric, say $g$ and $h$, but I do not assume the connections to be compatible with the metric on the bundle. It means that $\nabla^*\nabla$ and $-\operatorname{Tr}\nabla^2$ may be two different operators (from what follows it will be clear that they can't always have the same first order part). You seem to be interested in the latter, but I like the former better, so I will discuss both cases.

**The connection Laplacian $-\operatorname{Tr}\nabla^2$.**

Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector fields on the manifold. Recall that, by definition,
$$ \nabla^2s(X(x),Y(x))
 = \big(\nabla_X\nabla_Ys-\nabla_{\nabla^{TM}_XY}s\big)(x). $$
Then
$$ \big(\widetilde\nabla^2s-\nabla^2s\big)(X(x),Y(x))
 = \big(\nabla_XA_Ys+A_X\nabla_Ys\big)(x)
 + (\text{order zero}), $$
and in coordinates,
$$ \big(-\operatorname{Tr}\widetilde\nabla^2+\operatorname{Tr}\nabla^2\big)s
 = 2g^{ij}A_{i\beta}^\alpha\partial_js^\beta\epsilon_\alpha+(\text{order zero}).$$

If the difference is of order zero, then the first term must vanish for all $s$, and this will happen if and only if $A=0$.

**The Bochner Laplacian $\nabla^*\nabla$.**

A bit of computation shows that
$$ D:=\widetilde\nabla^*\widetilde\nabla - \nabla^*\nabla = A^*\nabla+\nabla^*A+A^*A, $$
and for every smooth function $f$ on $M$ with compact support,
$$ \pm[D,f] = A^*(\mathrm df\otimes{})-(\mathrm df\otimes{})^*A, $$
depending on your sign convention. In other words, in local coordinates,
$$ \pm[D,f]_\alpha^\beta = g^{ij}h_{\alpha\alpha'}A_{i\beta'}^{\alpha'}h^{\beta\beta'}\partial_jf - g^{ij}A_{i\alpha}^\beta\partial_jf. $$

If $D$ were an operator of order 0, then the above commutator should vanish, more or less by definition. In other words, we must have $\langle A-A^*,\mathrm df\rangle=0$ for all $f$ (up to choosing the right notations for everything). This shows that we must have $A=A^\star$, where the star denotes the adjoint with respect to the bundle only, i.e. $\langle A(x)v\otimes e,f\rangle_h=\langle e,A(x)^\star v\otimes f\rangle_h$ for all $v\in T_xM$, $e,f\in E$.

Now it should be clear from the previous expression that in fact, if $A=A^\star$ (which is easy to find), the Laplace operators will be the same up to a zeroth order term, so we do not have uniqueness. However, the usual condition that the operators be compatible with the metric impose $A=-A^\star$, so in this specific case (which is extremely common) we have uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Could you perhaps elaborate a bit on the implication$$g^{ij}A_i\partial_j=0\Rightarrow \forall i:A_i=0?$$

Comment: I understand that$$g^{ij}A_i\otimes \partial_j=0\in\Gamma(U,\mathrm{End}(E)\otimes TM)$$implies that$$\forall k:A_k=\langle g^{ij}A_i\otimes \partial_j,g_{k\ell}\mathrm dx^\ell\rangle=0.$$So you are claiming that$$g^{ij}A_i \partial_j=0\Rightarrow g^{ij}A_i\otimes \partial_j=0,$$right?

Comment: I thought that in your answer $g^{ij}A_i\partial_j$ is a first order differential operator on $\Gamma(U,E)$ (and hence an endomorphism on $\Gamma(U,E)$).

Comment: Sure. In this case, calling this operator $\mathcal A^\dagger$, apply it to a section that is $s=g_{k\ell}x^\ell\epsilon_\alpha$ in some chart centered at zero; it gives locally $\mathcal A^\dagger s=A_{k\alpha}^\beta\epsilon_\beta$, so $A_{k\alpha}^\beta$ must be zero on a neighborhood of zero in this chart for all $k,\alpha,\beta$. This is true around every point and for every indices, so it means that $A=0$.